# Consulta de foreingkey laravel con inertia

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código. Estoy realzando una consulta con 3 relaciones. En el segundo where estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda de la descripción de producto, pero no logro conseguirlo. Alguna idea. Estoy usando laravel con inertia.

```
$lista = ProductoSucursal::with('producto', 'moneda','categoria')
                ->where('sucursal_id','=', request()->input('sucursal'))
                ->where('producto.descripcion','like','%' . request()->input('search') . '%')
                ->paginate(5),
```

TABLA PRODUCTOSUCURSAL
ID
PRODUCTO_ID
SUCURSAL_ID

TABLA PRODUCTO
ID
DESCRIPCION
TIPO
PRECIO

Comment: Agrega tus tablas, de favor. Para conocer mejor la estructura de la consulta a realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes consultar la [Existencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), con lo cual, la consulta te devolverá sólo los `ProductoSucursal` que tengan relacionado un `producto` donde el campo `descripcion` contenga el valor de `request()->input('search')`:

```
ProductoSucursal::whereHas('producto', function ($query) {
    $query->where('descripcion', 'like', '%' . request()->input('search') . '%');
})
// ...
```

Todo junto en la consulta que muestras en la pregunta:

```
$lista = ProductoSucursal::whereHas('producto', function ($query) {
        $query->where('descripcion', 'like', '%' . request()->input('search') . '%');
    })
    ->where('sucursal_id','=', request()->input('sucursal'))
    ->with([
        'producto', 
        'moneda',
        'categoria'
    ])
    ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Comment: Y eso que es? javascript? no tiene nada que ver con laravel... Revisa tu frontend si estás intentando acceder a alguna propiedad `name` de algo que no está definido. Laravel sólo va a devolver un array vacío si no hay ningún registro que cumpla con las cláusulas `where`.

Comment: Claro, pero ese inertiajs

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en tu pregunta solo estas asignándole el resultado de una consulta a la BD a una variable. No sabemos nada más de tu proyecto de lo que expones en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo, pude resolverlo de esta manera.
'lista' => Sucursal::find(request()->input('sucursal'))
                    ->productos()
                    ->where('descripcion','like','%' . request()->input('search') . '%')
                    ->with('unidad','categoria','categoria.categoriaSuperior','marca')
                    ->paginate(5),

Comment: @LeandroCasapia Vale. Siendo tu enfoque algo diferente a lo propuesto en esta respuesta, te pediría que agregues la solución en otra respuesta, así le puede servir a otros que tengan el mismo problema.